# Performance overhead of resizing to 0 a multidimensional vector?

Tags: c++

Let's say I need to construct and frequently resize a vector of vectors of vectors as follows:

```
template <typename X>
class DB {
  vector<vector<vector<X>>> database;
  // hidden helper
  h_clear() {
    /* resize to 0 or iterate deleting? */
  }
public:
  DB(size_t size = 100) : database(100) {}

  ~DB() { h_clear(); }
```

I guess what I am trying to ask is whether I should start paying attention to performance overhead as the dimensions of vector increases. Above is a 3D vector but my question applies also to any n-dimension vectors (where n > 3).

For some theoretically large multidimensional dataset, at which level of dimensions should I start thinking about the efficiency of resizing?

For example, let's say I need to quickly clear the vector. But the vector is clearly very large, and perhaps blocking will occur when `.clear()` is called. In this situation, do I need a custom threaded function that run and clear in the background and how do I even start implementing this kind of solution?

Comment: I'd say that if you're worried at all about performance, you should be using a multiple-dimension array rather than a vector-of-vectors-of-vectors.  With a multiple-dimension array you at least have some hope of maintaining a good hit-miss ratio of your CPU's RAM caches; with vectors, your values are going to be stored all over the place.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't worry about the efficiency of resizing, unless I have performance/profiling data in realistic use cases that indicate a measurable performance concern, and that the code doing resizing of vectors is implicated.   Worry about getting the code working correctly (in terms of producing required outputs) first, then do the performance testing/profiling to identify any performance concerns.   Once there is evidence that resizing is causing a performance concern, then worry about options to deal with it (e.g. multi-dimensional array instead of nested vectors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use nested vectors. They're not allocated contiguously which can be a real problem when it comes to cache performance and confuses the pre-fetcher. Use *N* dimensional emulation with offsets, like `x + y * w` and so on.

The cost of releasing memory is generally trivial and won't "block" for any measurable period of time. Allocations have a fixed cost. What's expensive is doing *lots* of allocations, like you would here with the nested vectors. A single allocation of 16GB is as expensive as an allocation of 1B. Same with releasing.

If you're concerned about performance be sure you have a **measurable performance problem**. Until you do it's not a problem.

When you do, **instrument it** and find out what the actual issue is before just hacking around and making a mess of things.

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation does not have a fixed cost.   Patterns of allocation, deallocation, and reallocation are associated with variable cost, due to effects like memory fragmentation  (which means that a new allocation can't fit in a previously released block, so the memory manager must find/track a new block).

Comment: @Peter If you want to get academic about it, sure, there's slight variances, but this is a deep rabbit hole to jump into. It's also complicated because it depends on the OS and the allocator used, so no one answer fits all situations. In general it's *O(1)* though.

Comment: That assumes that inner vectors have the same size (as for matrices). It is not necessary the case. Might be the case for OP though.

Answer (score 1):

When you know the maximum size of the container in advance and the size is "very big" you may use .reserve. This makes really sense for the vector, when the maximum size will never change, and you still want to add entries dynamically and you want to iterate very fast.
For a list container this would not make sense. As the memory is not allocated as a continuous block.

Also test it on godbolt.org and do benchmarking with the tool quickbench which is available there.

As @tadman says the N dimensional emulation is the way to go, for i.e. a real matrix implementation.